# PHP - accessing global variables in all functions of class

Tags: php

I need to access some variables of an external php file in most of functions of a class. I'm accessing in following way (and it works fine)

```
class test{

function a(){ 
    global $myglobalvar ;
    ..
    ..
    }

function b(){ 
    global $myglobalvar ;
    ..
    ..
    }

function c(){ 
    global $myglobalvar ;
    ..
    ..
    }

}
```

Is there a way that i can access $myglobalvar in all functions of the class without declaring in each function? I did read that it can be done by declaring only once in the constructor of the class, but I dont know how to do it. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's PHP's way of telling you "stop this shit, you're doing it wrong(tm)". And mind you, PHP isn't one of those languages fanatic about good code.

Comment: @delnan: +1 for the first part -2 for the second.

Comment: make that variables in object level

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
class test{

 private $myglobalvar;

 public function __construct($var){
  $this->myglobalvar = $var;
 }

 function a(){ 
  echo $this->myglobalvar;
 }

 function b(){ 
  echo $this->myglobalvar; 
 }

 function c(){ 
  echo $this->myglobalvar;
 }

}

$test = new test("something");
$test->a(); // echos something
$test->b(); // echos something
$test->c(); // echos something
```

Comment: You are missing the global declaration

Comment: @RDL the whole point of this design is that the global is passed via the constructor so that the object's scope is properly insulated and isn't dependent on a specific naming of an external resource. Promotes reuse.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a **reference** to a global variable in the constructor (much like `global` would):

```
class test{

    function __construct() { 
        $this->myglobalvar = & $GLOBALS["myglobalvar"];
```

Which then allows aceess to the global via `$this->myglobalvar` in each method.

Comment: Sure that would work, but why teach people code smells like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you tell us more about this case, we might be able to tell you a better way to solve your problem. Globals should be avoided, whenever possible. Are you really talking about a variable or is it more like a configuration option that stays the same during a whole server roundtrip. In that case you could think of treating it like a configuration option and store it in a registry object (singleton).