# What to use instead of global in php

Tags: php

Is there any other way instead of using global everytime  I need to access a global variable inside a function?

```
$db = new ezSQL_mysql("root", "", "payroll", "localhost");

class employee{
  function get_emp(){
    global $db;

  }
}
```

Comment: Eh, I dunno, store a reference to `$db` in your `employee` instances?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - accessing global variables in all functions of class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212569/php-accessing-global-variables-in-all-functions-of-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In normal global-scope functions, either use the `global` keyword, or `$GLOBALS['db']` superglobal array (which is preferable for readability).  The other alternative is to pass the global variable into the function as a parameter.

In your class, the best method is dependency injection.  Your class constructor receives the `$db` as a parameter, which makes it available to all class methods:

```
// $db was created at global scope
$db = new ezSQL_mysql("root", "", "payroll", "localhost");

class employee {
  public $db;

  // $db already created in your script is passed as a dependency
  // to the class constructor
  public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  // Access it as $this->db inside the class
  public function get_emp() {
    do_something($this->db);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is it preferred `$GLOBALS['db']` over `global $db;`? I've seen http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php, but that page doesn't tell anything about a preferred method.

Comment: ok I get it. I suppose I'll stick to `global` then, as I seldom use global variables (and I know which they are). Also, I actually find that `$GLOBALS['foo']` is worse for readibility, but that's just me. Thank you for your reply.